# Windows 10 boot options after boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I was forced to reinstall Windows 10 on my dual boot (with ubuntu) machine. However after using Boot-Repair I get three windows boot options. The whole grub menu list is below:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced opions for Ubuntu
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi <-
Windows Boot UEFI loader <-
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2) <-
System setup
```

As I want to adjust my Grub menu I would like to remove some entries. However I am not sure if those Windows entries differ somehow, as all of those load Windows 10 properly. Which one should I choose to boot?